# How to fix "MavenInvocationException" in javadoc:fix

Tags: java, maven, plugins, javadoc

I'm getting this Exception if I try to execute the goal javadoc:fix.

```
Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:clirr-maven-plugin:2.2.2:check failed: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
```

If I remove all sourcecode from the src/main/java location it works perfectly fine. If I add a new class to the empty directory it works fine. 
But when I revert the deletion the error comes back.

So I think my sourcecode is "broken" where have I to search to find the "broken" file ?

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>some.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-arti-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/clirr-maven-plugin -->


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>some.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultAuthor>Author</defaultAuthor>
                    <defaultVersion>${project.version}</defaultVersion>
                    <version>true</version>
                    <author>true</author>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>update</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>fix</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>javadoc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException: Error when invoking Maven, consult the invoker log file: C:\some\folder\target\invoker\clirr-maven-plugin2009217175.txt
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.JavadocUtil.invokeMaven (JavadocUtil.java:886)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractFixJavadocMojo.executeClirr (AbstractFixJavadocMojo.java:700)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractFixJavadocMojo.execute (AbstractFixJavadocMojo.java:448)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)

And in the File there is this Exception:

Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:clirr-maven-plugin:2.2.2:check failed: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:clirr-maven-plugin:2.2.2:check (default-cli) on project net-wittlich-test: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:clirr-maven-plugin:2.2.2:check failed: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:clirr-maven-plugin:2.2.2:check failed: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant (Constant.java:146)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init> (ConstantPool.java:67)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool (ClassParser.java:222)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse (ClassParser.java:136)
    at org.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass (ClassLoaderRepository.java:94)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.getSuperClass (JavaClass.java:762)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.getAllInterfaces (JavaClass.java:803)
    at net.sf.clirr.core.internal.bcel.BcelJavaType.getAllInterfaces (BcelJavaType.java:78)
    at net.sf.clirr.core.internal.checks.InterfaceSetCheck.check (InterfaceSetCheck.java:58)
    at net.sf.clirr.core.Checker.runClassChecks (Checker.java:190)
    at net.sf.clirr.core.Checker.reportDiffs (Checker.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.clirr.AbstractClirrMojo.executeClirr (AbstractClirrMojo.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.clirr.AbstractClirrMojo.executeClirr (AbstractClirrMojo.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.clirr.ClirrCheckMojo.execute (ClirrCheckMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

If I clear my local repo I get only a Warning "[WARNING] No previous artifact has been deployed, Clirr is ignored."

But as soon I change the Version higher and there a two versions of my artifact in my repo I still get the error.

I think I have found the important part in the javadoc-maven-plugin 
https://github.com/apache/maven-javadoc-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/javadoc/AbstractFixJavadocMojo.java

Line: 193-205 - Why it is hardcoded ?
Line: 450 The Try / catch to execute the Clirr

Comment: Sounds like the code is compiled with an incompatible java version. Can you upgrade the cirr plugin to the latest version (2.8) and see if the problem is fixed?

Comment: My target and source version is "8". I'm use the version 3.1.0 from the maven-javadoc-plugin. And the javadoc plugin seems to use cirr 2.2.2. I don't know how to tell a plugin to use a different dependency - is it even possible ?

Comment: now I have tried to force the plugin to use an other version still no result.

Comment: clirr is a little old ...I would recommend to remove it ...

Comment: javadoc seems to use it - is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stacktrace the actual library causing problems is bcel. It might work if you add a new version as plugin dependency to your maven config.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- .... other stuff -->
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
         <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
         <version>6.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

---

If that doesn't work, i would go for this workaround. Find the classes that causes the problem and exclude them.

To find the classes that cause problems:

1. Add an exception breakpoint to `org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException`
2. Start the maven generation in debug mode
3. Wait till the breakpoint is reached
4. Look at the `org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse` activation frame, i would expect to see the classname in one of the variables or fields. (Maybe you need to look around further down the stack).
5. Exclude the class (maybe the whole package)
6. Repeat at 2

Comment: Thanks for this answer - but I can't help me. I added the breakpoint run it in debug mode and the Error still appears without triggering the breakpoint.